# Installing and running pypy on linux

Tags: python, linux, installation, pypy

I have been attempting to install and run pypy3 on a linux machine but am running into troubles. I have been using pypy on a mac but installed it using homebrew so didn't encounter any of these troubles.

I downloaded the most recent build and unpacked the tar file as described by [their documentation](http://doc.pypy.org/en/release-2.5.x/install.html). I followed the steps exactly (except replacing pypy with pypy3 and using the appropriate file name). However, when typing

```
./pypy3-v6.0.0-linux64/bin/pypy3
```

I get the following error:

```
./pypy3-v6.0.0-linux64/bin/pypy3: error while loading shared libraries: libbz2.so.1.0: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this error. Despite the pypy documentation saying that it should run in place, `pypy3 filename.py` still returns the error:

```
If 'pypy3' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that 
contains it, like this:
cnf pypy3
```

But `cnf pypy3` only confirms that the pypy3 is not found.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using?

Comment: run `ldd ./pypy3-v6.0.0-linux64/bin/pypy3` and check the missing libs

Comment: My linux distribution is openSUSE 11.2 (x86_64).
I appear to be missing GLIBC_2.11, GLIBC_2.14, and GLIBC_2.15.

Comment: openSUSE 11.2: Released **2009-11-12**. The `bz2` version is 1.05 . `libbz2.so.1.0` came with `bz2` version is 1.0.6 . "GLIBC_2.11, GLIBC_2.14, and GLIBC_2.15" are objects in the  much later system library `glibc-2.15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those distributions are for debian linux only. You may have better luck with the [portable binaries](https://github.com/squeaky-pl/portable-pypy#portable-pypy-distribution-for-linux) if the ones provided by OpenSuse are too old for you.

Edit: note that you used a link to an old version of the documents, you should have looked [here](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html) which states "These builds depend on dynamically linked libraries that may not be available on your OS"